# Push notifications are not working on iOS

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gluon, gluon-mobile, gluonfx

I configured my app project starting from the documentation https://docs.gluonhq.com/ and using the GluonFX Gradle plugins.
But the push notifications are not working on iOS.
It is not displayed in the notification center, nor on the lock screen, nor in the banner.
Any solution?

Comment: Impossible to say what's happening to you if you don't post: your gradle build with versions and dependencies, some code on how you use the PushNotifications service, your logs from your iOS device (do you get a token?). It is convenient to use `System.setProperty(com.gluonhq.attach.util.Constants.ATTACH_DEBUG, "true");` to get a more verbose output to console (build, deploy and run `gluonfx:nativerun` again, then post the relevant parts).

Comment: @JoséPereda https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/issues/114

Comment: You don't need all of these: `implementation group: 'com.gluonhq.attach'...`, that's taken care of by the gluonfx plugin via `attachConfig`. Also run with my comment above, and post your logs. Without logs nobody will be able to help you.